# Wpf DataGrid Only updates when clicking into Cell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged, caliburn

I am slowing teaching myself WPF with Calburn and then hopefully Rx.

My current objective is to Bind a DataGrid to a collection of "stock" and then update the prices of each stock and have it display in my View in real time. Eventually I'd like to use Rx to do this but for now I am just using Wpf/Mvvm & Caliburn Micro.

However my datagrid's price column only displays the updated price when I click into the individual price cells and not automatically. Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

My view is:

```
<Window x:Class="StockPriceSim.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:StockPriceSim.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:StockPriceSim.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}">
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Stocks" ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks, Mode=OneWay,     NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And my view Model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using StockPriceSim.Model;

namespace StockPriceSim.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var initialData = new List<Stock>();

            initialData.Add(new Stock {CurrencyCode = "GBP", CurrentPrice = 102.11, Id = 1, LongName = "BP Long Name", ShortName = "BPP"});
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "GBP", CurrentPrice = 99.99, Id = 2, LongName = "RBS Long Name", ShortName = "RBS" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "EUR", CurrentPrice = 97.00, Id = 3, LongName = "BNPP LongName", ShortName = "BNP" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "EUR", CurrentPrice = 112.15, Id = 4, LongName = "Deutsche Long Name", ShortName = "DSH" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "USD", CurrentPrice = 98.25, Id = 5, LongName = "General Motors", ShortName = "GMM" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "USD", CurrentPrice = 131.12, Id = 6, LongName = "Microsfot", ShortName = "MSF" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "EUR", CurrentPrice = 95.66, Id = 7, LongName = "Santandar", ShortName = "SDT" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "CAD", CurrentPrice = 104.56, Id = 8, LongName = "Royal Mounties", ShortName = "RYM" });
            initialData.Add(new Stock { CurrencyCode = "ZAR", CurrentPrice = 103.29, Id = 9, LongName = "Standard Long Name", ShortName = "STF" });

            Stocks = new ObservableCollection<Stock>(initialData);

            Task.Run(() => UpdateStocks());
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Stock> _stocks;

        public ObservableCollection<Stock> Stocks
        {
            get { return _stocks; }
            set
            {
                _stocks = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Stocks);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateStocks()
        {
            var random = new Random();

            while (true)
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => PerformUpdate(random));
            }
        }

        private void PerformUpdate(Random random)
        {
            foreach (var stock in Stocks)
            {
                double next = random.NextDouble()*(110.0 - 90.0) + 90.0;

                stock.CurrentPrice = next;                
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you haven't implemented **`INotifyPropertyChanged`** on class Stock.

Make sure property change event is raised when any property gets set so that UI gets refreshed.

```
public double CurrentPrice
{
    get
    { 
        return currentPrice;
    }
    set
    {
        if (currentPrice != value)
        {
            currentPrice = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also on side not ***no need to invoke PerformUpdate on any dispatcher*** and anyhow *Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will get you dispatcher of same thread* on which you are executing so queueing it on itself doesn't make any sense.

```
while (true)
{
    PerformUpdate(random);
}
```